# ServiceStack TypeInitializationException on Apphost.Start()

Tags: c#, servicestack

I am using ServiceStack in standalone mode.  It is now giving a `TypeInitialzationException` when executing `Apphost.Start()`.

At the time, I was working on implementing some custom filters, but removing the annotation from the only filtered DTO class did not solve the problem.

The stack trace does not show any of my classes involved, and the failing class is the `JsvReader` which I don't use explicitly.

How can prevent this problem?

Note:  I just used nuget to update all packages, so this is current as of now, 3.9.43 for all ServiceStack components.

## Exception Detail

```
System.TypeInitializationException occurred
  HResult=-2146233036
  Message=The type initializer for 'ServiceStack.Text.Jsv.JsvReader`1' threw an exception.
  Source=ServiceStack.Text
  TypeName=ServiceStack.Text.Jsv.JsvReader`1
  StackTrace:
       at ServiceStack.Text.Jsv.JsvReader`1.GetParseFn()
       at ServiceStack.Text.Jsv.JsvReader.GetParseFn(Type type)
       at ServiceStack.ServiceModel.Serialization.StringMapTypeDeserializer..ctor(Type type)
       at ServiceStack.ServiceHost.RestPath..ctor(Type requestType, String path, String verbs, String summary, String notes)
       at ServiceStack.ServiceHost.ServiceController.RegisterRestPaths(Type requestType)
       at ServiceStack.ServiceHost.ServiceController.RegisterCommon(Type serviceType, Type requestType, Type responseType)
       at ServiceStack.ServiceHost.ServiceController.RegisterNService(ITypeFactory serviceFactoryFn, Type serviceType)
       at ServiceStack.ServiceHost.ServiceController.Register(ITypeFactory serviceFactoryFn)
       at ServiceStack.ServiceHost.ServiceManager.Init()
       at ServiceStack.WebHost.Endpoints.Support.HttpListenerBase.Init()
       at ArdWebServer.Program.Main(String[] args)
  InnerException: System.TypeInitializationException
       HResult=-2146233036
       Message=The type initializer for 'ServiceStack.Text.Common.DeserializeSpecializedCollections`2' threw an exception.
       Source=ServiceStack.Text
       TypeName=ServiceStack.Text.Common.DeserializeSpecializedCollections`2
       StackTrace:
            at ServiceStack.Text.Common.DeserializeSpecializedCollections`2.get_Parse()
            at ServiceStack.Text.Common.JsReader`1.GetCoreParseFn[T]()
            at ServiceStack.Text.Common.JsReader`1.GetParseFn[T]()
            at ServiceStack.Text.Jsv.JsvReader`1..cctor()
       InnerException: System.NullReferenceException
            HResult=-2147467261
            Message=Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
            Source=ServiceStack.Text
            StackTrace:
                 at ServiceStack.Text.PlatformExtensions.GenericTypeArguments(Type type)
                 at ServiceStack.Text.Common.DeserializeSpecializedCollections`2.GetGenericEnumerableParseFn()
                 at ServiceStack.Text.Common.DeserializeSpecializedCollections`2.GetParseFn()
                 at ServiceStack.Text.Common.DeserializeSpecializedCollections`2..cctor()
            InnerException:
```

## My App host

```
    public class AppHost : AppHostHttpListenerBase
    {
        public AppHost() : base("IAM Tools Service Stack Host", typeof (Tims.Global).Assembly)
        {                
            CatchAllHandlers.Add(
                (httpMethod, pathInfo, filePath) => 
                    Tims.Support.StaticFileHandler.Factory(
                        Params.Instance.HttpDataDir, 
                        "/", 
                        pathInfo
                )
            );
        }

        public override void Configure(Funq.Container container)
        {                
            SetConfig(new EndpointHostConfig()
                      {

                          DebugMode = true,

                          WriteErrorsToResponse = true
                      });        
        }
    }
```